# Comparing the field of last element of an array with the parent document's field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to compare parent document's embedded field to the last document's embedded field (present inside of an array) which is also part of the parent document and return the documents' `externalIds` when those two fields don't match.

For reference here are images:
[The actual metaddata containing the array][1]
[Here is the another image containing the field][2]

So in the second image I actually want only last revision i.e last document in the revisions array to be compared with parent document and the field that needs to be compared with is `metadata.formData.mergeStatus.status`.
I want those document `_id`s where the lastdocument present in the array has a different field than its parent document's respective field, if at all the revision array exist.

I am new to mongodb,and asking for the first time in stackoverflow so if you find it dumb please excuse me, however here is my attempt.

```
db.document.aggregate([
    { $match: { $and: [
        { spaceId: 3007 },
        { revisions: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } } }
    ] } },
    { $project:
        { _id: 1,
        spaceId:1,
        externalId:1,
        revisions: { $cond: {
            if: { $isArray: "$revisions" },
            then: { $size: "$revisions" },
            else: "NA" } },
        last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$revisions", -1 ] },
        difference: { $ne: [
            "last.metadata.formData.mergeStatus.status", 
            "metadata.formData.mergeStatus.status" ] }
        }
    }
]); 

The above suggestion really helps however i am confused for below scenario,
so the metadata field contains elementsData and inside of that is another embedded object signature, which has two string fields 
1.userSignatureDate(String)
2.userSignatureText(String)
so when i have applied above logic to compare the *userSignatureDate* of parent metadata with respective field in last document of  the revisions array.it is not giving actual results.
here is the image for the code that i had written and the sample metadata Structure .[enter image description here][3][enter image description here][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsrKv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6wsp.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/398I8.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYUAL.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{$project:
      {
          status: "$metadata.formData.mergeStatus.status", 
          last_revisions: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$revisions", -1 ] }
      }},
{$project:
    {
        matched:{
            $eq:[
            "$status",
            "$last_revisions.metadata.formData.mergeStatus.status"
            ]}
       }}
])
```

Comment: Can you @Imran please see the above edit and suggest something.